# Editing template .twig files in backend but not change in theme folder in opencart.?

Tags: opencart

If I go into `Admin -> Design -> Theme Editor -> product.twig` and make a test change (e.g. adding an H1) then save & reload the front-end, the change shows up.

However, if I open the file `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.twig` the change is NOT there.

So, 2 questions:

1. If the change that's made in admin is *not* saved in the `file`, then *where* is it saved?
2. If it's saved somewhere else, why is there a template file, if it does nothing?
   [image]

Comment: Are u sure u are using the `default` theme?

Comment: yes i change default theme product.twig

Comment: That I can tell yes, but are u using it? It's the only theme installed in your project?

Comment: some client not give the login credential.so how changes made in theme